# Snowflake: How to get timestamp with TZ offset from TIME_LOCAL and TIME_UTC and/or DST_OFFSET_minutes?

Tags: sql, timestamp, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dst

I'm struggling with something related to timestamps.
I have a table with:

- LOCAL_TS (TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
- UTC_TS (TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
- DST_OFFSET_MINUTES(NUMBER(4,0)
- LATITUDE
- LONGITUDE

is there any way to infer the timezone through the coordinates or the two timestamp?
Something like having this varchar "2020-11-02T17:00:00-0500" with local + the offset?

Comment: share some sample data and desired results please

Comment: 2022-10-17 10:15:00.000 2022-10-17 03:15:00.000 -60
are, respectively, UTC_TS, LOCAL_TS and DST_OFFSET_MINUTES. I would like to obtain ISO 8601 , like [ISO]
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-NNNN; NNNN=GMT offset.
I also have lat/long for that in case it helps.
2014-08-20T10:47:59-0500

Comment: so if you have the two times, and the DST offset (aka 0 or 60 minutes being the standards) you can with a prune a list of "all timezones" for all time (as they change over time) and then do a geometry intersection look-up on the remainders, to find the timezone at play at that time & location.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim could you kindly provide some example?

Comment: Which part was too vague?

Answer (score 0):

So part one, big table of timezones, and years/time they are in affect verse data you have:

```
with table_of_timezone as (
    select 
        column1 as tz_name, 
        try_to_timestamp_ntz(column2) as utc_from,
        try_to_timestamp_ntz(column3) as utc_to
    from values
    ('nzst', '2022-04-03 02:00:00', '2022-09-25 02:00:00'),
    ('nzdt', '2022-09-25 02:00:00', '2023-04-02 02:00:00'),
    ('aest', '2022-10-02 02:00:00', '2023-04-02 02:00:00')
), data(LOCAL_TS, UTC_TS, DST_OFFSET_MINUTES, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) as (
    select 
        try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1),
        try_to_timestamp_ntz(column2),
        column3, column4, column5
    from values 
        ('2022-10-18 22:20:00', '2022-10-18 09:20:00', 60, -43.5320, 172.6306) -- Christchurch NZ
)
select d.*
    ,t.*
from data as d
join table_of_timezone as t
    on d.UTC_TS between t.utc_from and t.utc_to 
        and d.UTC_TS < t.utc_to
```

gives only two timezones that could be in play:

| LOCAL_TS | UTC_TS | DST_OFFSET_MINUTES | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | TZ_NAME | UTC_FROM | UTC_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 22:20:00.000 | 2022-10-18 09:20:00.000 | 60 | -43.532 | 172.6306 | nzdt | 2022-09-25 02:00:00.000 | 2023-04-02 02:00:00.000 |
| 2022-10-18 22:20:00.000 | 2022-10-18 09:20:00.000 | 60 | -43.532 | 172.6306 | aest | 2022-10-02 02:00:00.000 | 2023-04-02 02:00:00.000 |

then if in your timezone tables you also store a [POLYGON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_makepolygon.html) to can do the more expensive intersection test, with the Lat/Lon.

Comment: The problem is that I Don't have timezone anywhere! Only lat, long, UTC TS ,Local Ts (both in Timestamp_NTZ) and dst_offset_minutrs, not timezone string ISO.